# Abrir calculadora de Windows desde el HTML de una página web

Tags: html, angular

Quiero hacer que cuando un usuario pulsa a un `<a>` o un `<button>` se abra la calculadora de Windows:

```
<button onclick="window.open('file:\\\C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe')">
  abrir calculadora
</button>

<a href = "C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe"> ir </a>
```

Lo que consigo es que se descargue la calculadora y si le pincho se ejecuta, pero yo lo que quiero es que se ejecute directamente.

La idea es saber como sería en el HTML para lanzarlo más tarde en Angular. Lo comento por si Angular puede gestionarlo mejor, aunque he mirado información y no veo como lanzarlo desde Angular.

Comment: Se puede hacer fácilmente, aunque requiere de una pequeña configuración en el cliente. ¿Qué versión de sistema operativo y navegador usan tus clientes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Por seguridad no se pueden ejecutar automáticamente aplicaciones desde el navegador, pero los sistemas operativos permiten integrar aplicaciones mediante URIs personalizadas.

En Windows puedes asociar la calculadora de Windows a la URI personalizada `calculadora://` siguiendo las instrucciones de la [documentación de Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)).

### Creando una URI personalizada en Windows

Creamos un archivo llamado `calculadora.reg` que contenga el siguiente contenido (hay que teclear el nombre del archivo entre comillas si usamos el bloc de notas para que no agregue `.txt` al final):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\calculadora]
@="URL:Apertura de calculadora"
"EditFlags"=dword:00210000
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\calculadora\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe,1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\calculadora\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\calculadora\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\calculadora\shell\open\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe"
```

Tras guardar el archivo hacemos doble clic sobre él para agregarlo al registro de Windows.

Si no eres el usuario *Administrador* deberás abrir una ventana de *Símbolo del sistema* como *Administrador* pulsando el botón derecho sobre la aplicación y luego pulsando en *Ejecutar como administrador*.

Una vez en un símbolo del sistema como usuario *Administrador* tecleamos:

```
regedit <ruta>\calculadora.reg
```

Donde `<ruta>` es la ruta donde guardaste el archivo generado anteriormente.

Ya está definida la URI personalizada, ahora deberemos crear el HTML que use dicha URI.

## Usando una URI personalizada en HTML

Ahora modificamos nuestro HTML, para hacer uso de la URI personalizada que hemos creado, de la siguiente manera:

```
<a href="calculadora://">Abrir la calculadora</a>
```

Si usas Chrome te saldrá una advertencia de seguridad que podrás quitar si marcas la opción "Abrir siempre este tipo de enlaces en la aplicación asociada".

PD: Este procedimiento varía en sistemas operativos Linux. Si algún cliente lo usa házmelo saber y te digo cómo proceder en ese caso.

Comment: No se puede importar C:\Users.... el archivo especificado no es un script de registro. Sólo es para usuarios de windows. Gracias !

Comment: Debes tener en cuenta que debe tener la extensión `.reg`. Si usas el bloc de notas debes poner entre comillas el nombre del archivo para que mantenga la extensión que le pongas, en caso contrario le concatenará `.txt` al nombre.

Comment: Si, le ha cambiado la extensión y aparece con el icono de los .reg, pero da ese error.

Comment: Disculpa, se quedó una línea sin agregar al bloque de código. Revisa el contenido del archivo ahora (no incluí la línea que pone `Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00` al darle a bloque de código).

Comment: Perfecto, te daba 100 puntazos !

Comment: De nada, ¡un placer ser de ayuda! :D

Answer (score 2):

lo que pides no se puede hacer, pues el navegador no puede salir de su ámbito.
Si lo piensas tiene su lógica, imagínate una pagina que busque el 'mal', te abre la calculadora con un bucle infinito y que pasaría?.
Quien dice la calculadora dice que te pone minar o cualquier cosa.
Espero te sirva de ayuda.
Como solución puedes desarrollar un calculadora online y ponerla como iframe
;)

Comment: Ya, lo entiendo, es como si un <a> et hiciera un format c: lo va a impedir por temas de seguridad, la cuestión es que tenemos una app del año chinpúm que si abre la calculadora en la web, creo que es por temas del ActiveX para IE, la cosa sería hacerlo igual pero para Chrome y MZ, en fin ,gracias.

Comment: Hace años había una brecha, no un abismo, de seguridad impresionante! jajaja