# Abrir DashBoard_PowerBI.bat desde HTML en Chrome

Tags: html, windows, google-chrome

Quiero ejecutar el archivo ejecutable `DashBoard_PowerBI.bat` en HTML desde el navegador Chrome.

Mi código HTML es es siguiente:

```
  <input type="button" value="bi" onclick="window.open('\\gdjnt453\BusinessIntelillence\content\DashBoard_PowerBI.bat')"/>
```

[image: Captura de pantalla de la página]

Al hacer clic en el botón no hace nada.

Comment: Eso no va a funcionar por cuestiones de seguridad. Chrome no va a dejar que se ejecute nada en la máquina

Comment: Gran _nonono_. Ese es el tipo de acciones que el navegador no va a permitir porque sería terriblemente inseguro.

Comment: Puede hacerse, pero requiere de la preparación previa del equipo y en principio no podrás ejecutar cualquier BAT, pero con un buen diseño podrás ejecutar lo que desees. ¿Qué sistema operativo usarán tus usuarios? ¿Windows o Linux?

Comment: @OscarGarcia usaran windows.

Comment: Ya he creado la respuesta. Espero que te sea de ayuda. Si tienes algún inconveniente en algún paso házmelo saber, hace tiempo que no lo hago en la práctica y puede que algo haya cambiado. Funcionaba en Windows 7 y tanto Chrome como en varias versiones de Internet Explorer.

Comment: He corregido el título de tu pregunta porque en ella hablas de abrir un BAT y viendo el contenido del código HTML lo que intentas es abrir un ejecutable.

Comment: @OscarGarcia muchas gracias pero en realidad si es un .bat, el error fue mio. al no ver que era .exe. deja la edito

Comment: ¿Has podido revisar mi respuesta? ¿Se sirvió? Debes reemplazar el .exe por .bat pero debería funcionarte sin problemas.

Comment: @OscarGarcia si sirvio tu respuesta. disculpa por no contestar antes. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por seguridad, y por norma general, no se pueden ejecutar automáticamente aplicaciones desde el navegador, pero los sistemas operativos permiten integrar aplicaciones mediante URIs o esquemas de URIs personalizadas.

En Windows puedes asociar tu archivo ejecutable al esquema URI personalizado `dashboardpowerbi:` siguiendo las instrucciones de la [documentación de Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)).

### Creando un esquema URI personalizado en Windows

Creamos un archivo llamado `dashboardpowerbi.reg` que contenga el siguiente contenido (hay que teclear el nombre del archivo entre comillas si usamos el bloc de notas para que no agregue `.txt` al final):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\dashboardpowerbi]
@="URL:Apertura de DashBoard_PowerBI"
"EditFlags"=dword:00210000
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\dashboardpowerbi\DefaultIcon]
@="\\\\gdjnt453\\BusinessIntelillence\\content\\DashBoard_PowerBI.exe,1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\dashboardpowerbi\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\dashboardpowerbi\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\dashboardpowerbi\shell\open\command]
@="\\\\gdjnt453\\BusinessIntelillence\\content\\DashBoard_PowerBI.exe"
```

Tras guardar el archivo hacemos doble clic sobre él para agregarlo al registro de Windows.

Si no eres el usuario *Administrador* deberás abrir una ventana de *Símbolo del sistema* como *Administrador* pulsando el botón derecho sobre la aplicación y luego pulsando en *Ejecutar como administrador*.

Una vez en un símbolo del sistema como usuario *Administrador* tecleamos:

```
regedit <ruta>\dashboardpowerbi.reg
```

Donde `<ruta>` es la ruta donde guardaste el archivo generado anteriormente.

Ya está definida la URI personalizada, ahora deberemos crear el HTML que use dicha URI.

## Usando el esquema URI personalizado en HTML

Ahora modificamos nuestro HTML, para hacer uso de la URI personalizada que hemos creado, de la siguiente manera:

```
<a href="dashboardpowerbi://">Abrir DashBoard_PowerBI</a>
```

Si usas Chrome te saldrá una advertencia de seguridad que podrás quitar si marcas la opción "Abrir siempre este tipo de enlaces en la aplicación asociada".

PD: Este procedimiento varía en sistemas operativos Linux. Si algún cliente lo usa házmelo saber y te digo cómo proceder en ese caso.

PD2: Respuesta adaptada de mi respuesta a [Abrir calculadora de Windows desde el HTML de una página web](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/286235/abrir-calculadora-de-windows-desde-el-html-de-una-p%C3%A1gina-web/286240#286240).